# How to pass actor dependencies when using Dependency Injection in Akkanet

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, akka.net

Assuming that I have a actor `MyActor` with the following constructor

```
public MyActor(IInterface someDependency, IActorRef actor1, IActorRef actor2, IActorRef actor3)
```

I'm using dependency injection with `actorSystem.DI().Props`, so I'm getting the actor using this line:

```
var myActorRef = _actorSystem.ActorOf(_actorSystem.DI().Props<MyActor>());
```

I have other actors, like **MyActor1**, **MyActor2**, **MyActor3**. So I want to actor1 parameter should be the ref of MyActor1, and so on.

How can I create the MyActor with the dependencies filled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use property injection instead of constructor injection, which isn't supported as you see. It also depends on your DI framework.
I'm using MEF and property injection for my actors. A little example of how I do this can be found in this article - http://usemam.blogspot.ru/2015/09/unit-testing-akkanet-actors-and-mef.html